# Symfony2 reusable entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I a project of mine I need to define two bundles A and B.
In project A I have an entity A.E and in project B I have an entity B.E.

I need a bidirectionnal relationship between A.E and B.E. But I also need to be able to replace bundle B by another bundle C that would have an entity C.E. I will then replace the A.E-B.E bidirectional relationship by a A.E-C.E identical relation.

It seems that I cannot define a bidirectional relation ship in doctrine 2 to be reusable:

```
// pseudo PHP, just to illustrate.

/**
 * @manyToOne(targetEntity=B.E)
 * @entity
 */
class A.E() {}

/**
 * @oneToMany(targetEntity=B.E)
 * @entity
 */
class B.E() {}
```

I can't replace B.E by C.E without changing A.E. I'm used to the python Django ORM where I don't need to declare a relation between two entity in each of them, thus allowing to build reusable entity models.

I can't find a way to build such a reusable model with symfony2. I may have misunderstood something or be going the wrong way. Ay help on that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your reusable entity to be related to an interface. Basically:

```
class MyReusableEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyVendor\MyBundle\MyInterface")
     * @var MyInterface
     */
    protected $myInterfaceRelation;
}
```

And in each project you use it:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        resolve_target_entities:
            MyVendor\MyBundle\MyInterface: My\Concrete\Class
```

Docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html

Comment: Thanks. So I imagine I can do the same thing to have reusable abstract superclass.